# PayPal PayFlow Pro Auth Failure

Tags: .net, authentication, curl, paypal, postman

I've setup a test account for PayPal Payflow Pro, but I'm having authentication issues.  Unless i'm using cURL, the api returns "User authentication failed".  I am sure I'm passing the same information as I've copied and pasted from the working cURL to PostMan and .net.  Am trying to replicate an example API call from:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payflow/gs-ppa-hosted-pages/#make-your-first-call

I'd appreciatie any help with this.

[image: cURL Example]

Postman failure:

[image: Postman failure]

.Net failure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any special characters in your password?

Try using length tags for your NVP parameters: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payflow/integration-guide/simple-transaction/#use-special-characters-in-values

Also make sure the SecureTokenID is unique in every request

Also don't think you should be URL encoding values for Payflow

Comment: Thanks Preston.  There were no special characters in the password.  Changing the body to raw text and concatenating the parameters worked.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to see exactly how I changed Postman and .net to work.  Thanks again to Preston PHX!

Text Body:
PARTNER=PayPal&VENDOR=&USER=&PWD=&TRXTYPE=S&AMT=40&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&SECURETOKENID=
[image]

.Net Code:

```
private string GetSecureToken(string amount, string trxtype)
{
var secure = new SecureTokenRequest(true)
{
    PARTNER = PartnerId,
    VENDOR = VendorId,
    USER = User,
    PWD = Password,
    AMT = amount,
    TRXTYPE = trxtype
    //CREATESECURETOKEN is set by boolean in SecureTokenRequest constructor
    //SECURETOKENID is set in SecureTokenRequest constructor using new Guid to string
};

var client = new RestClient(Uri);

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

var parameterDict = new Dictionary<string,string>()
{
    {nameof(secure.PARTNER), secure.PARTNER},
    {nameof(secure.VENDOR), secure.VENDOR},
    {nameof(secure.USER), secure.USER},
    {nameof(secure.PWD), secure.PWD},
    {nameof(secure.TRXTYPE), secure.TRXTYPE},
    {nameof(secure.AMT), secure.AMT},
    {nameof(secure.CREATESECURETOKEN), secure.CREATESECURETOKEN},
    {nameof(secure.SECURETOKENID), secure.SECURETOKENID},
};

var parameterList = parameterDict.Select(kvp
    => $"{kvp.Key}={kvp.Value}").ToList();

var postBody = string.Join("&", parameterList);

request.AddParameter("text", postBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);

var response = client.Execute(request);

var responseContent = response.IsSuccessful
    ? response.Content
    : $"{response.StatusCode} : {response.ErrorMessage}";

return responseContent;
}
```